# How to sort a group of data in a columnwise manner?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

I have a group of data like the attached **raw data**, when I sort the raw data by **sort -n** , the data were sorted line by line, the output looks like this:

```
 3  6  9  22
 2  3  4  5
 1  7  16 20
```

I want to sort the data in a columnwise manner, the output would look like this:

```
 1  2  4  3
 3  6  9  16
 5  7  20 22
```

Ok, I did try something.

My primary ideal is to extract the data columnwise and then sort and then paste them, but I can't get through. Here is my script:

```
for ((i=1; i<=4; i=i+1)) 
do 
     awk '{print $i}' file | sort -n >>output
done
```

The output:

```
1  7  20 16
3  6  9  22
5  2  4  3
1  7  20 16
3  6  9  22
5  2  4  3
1  7  20 16
3  6  9  22
5  2  4  3
1  7  20 16
3  6  9  22
5  2  4  3
```

It seems that *$i* is unchangeable and equals to $0

Thanks a lot.

```
 raw data1

 3  6  9  22
 5  2  4  3
 1  7  20 16

raw data2

488.000000 1236.000000 984.000000 2388.000000 788.000000 704.000000
600.000000 1348.000000 872.000000 2500.000000 900.000000 816.000000
232.000000 516.000000 1704.000000 1668.000000 68.000000 16.000000
244.000000 504.000000 1716.000000 1656.000000 56.000000 28.000000
2340.000000 3088.000000 868.000000 4240.000000 2640.000000 2556.000000
2588.000000 3336.000000 1116.000000 4488.000000 2888.000000 2804.000000
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me introduce a flexible solution using `cut` and `sort` that you can use on any `M,N` size tab delimited input matrix.

```
$ cat -vTE data_to_sort.in 
3^I6^I9^I22$
5^I2^I4^I3$
1^I7^I20^I16$

$ col=4; line=3; 
$ for i in $(seq ${col}); do cut -f$i data_to_sort.in |\
> sort -n; done | paste $(for i in $(seq ${line}); do echo -n "- "; done) |\
> datamash transpose
1       2       4       3
3       6       9       16
5       7       20      22
```

If the input file is not `\t` delimited you need to define proper delimiter to using `-d"$DELIM_CHAR"` have the cut working properly.

- `for i in $(seq ${col}); do cut -f$i data_to_sort.in | sort -n; done` will separate each column of the file and sort it
- `paste $(for i in $(seq ${line}); do echo -n "- "; done)` the paste column will then recreate a matrix structure
- `datamash transpose` is needed to transpose the intermediate matrix

Thanks to the feedback from **Sundeep**, let me introduce to you a **better** solution using `pr` instead of `paste` command to generate the columns:

```
$ col=4; line=3 
$ for i in $(seq ${col}); do cut -f$i data_to_sort.in |\
> sort -n; done | pr -${line}ats | datamash transpose
```

Last but not least,

```
$ col=4; for i in $(seq ${col}); do cut -f$i data_to_sort.in |\
> sort -n; done | pr -${col}ts                                                    
1       2       4       3
3       6       9       16
5       7       20      22
```

The following solution will allow us to not use datamash at all!!!

(many thanks to **Sundeep**)

**Proof that is working for the skeptics and the downvoters...**

[image: Proof that is working for the skeptics...]

**2nd run with 6 columns:**

```
$ col=6; for i in $(seq ${col}); do cut -f$i <(sed 's/^ \+//g;s/ \+/\t/g' data2) | sort -n; done | pr -${col}ts | tr '\t' '  '                 
232.000000 504.000000 868.000000 1656.000000 56.000000 16.000000
244.000000 516.000000 872.000000 1668.000000 68.000000 28.000000
488.000000 1236.000000 984.000000 2388.000000 788.000000 704.000000
600.000000 1348.000000 1116.000000 2500.000000 900.000000 816.000000
2340.000000 3088.000000 1704.000000 4240.000000 2640.000000 2556.000000
2588.000000 3336.000000 1716.000000 4488.000000 2888.000000 2804.000000
```

[image]

Comment: could split the code in multiple lines to make it easier to read :) also, you can use `pr` instead of `paste`, it allows numeric argument.. for ex: `pr -3ats`

Comment: check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308631/how-to-process-a-multi-column-text-file-to-get-another-multi-column-text-file as well

Comment: and just realized, you could avoid datamash altogether by using `pr -${col}ts`

Comment: @Y.Du: could you also `vote up` my answer? For your other question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169847/how-to-subtract-a-value-with-a-column-of-values it is currently in `hold` status so I can't answer it :(

Comment: @Allan: ***Please don't ask people to up vote your posts***

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!!

```
awk '{f1[NR]=$1; f2[NR]=$2; f3[NR]=$3; f4[NR]=$4} 
  END{asort(f1); asort(f2); asort(f3); asort(f4); 
      for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) print f1[i],f2[i],f3[i],f4[i]}' file

1 2 4 3
3 6 9 16
5 7 20 22
```

there may a smarter way of doing this as well...

Comment: You should mention thats gawk-only for asort().

Comment: @karakfa: Thanks a lot. Your solution works well in this 3*4 data array, but what if I have a data with a size of n*m?

Comment: I would write a script writing script, that will produce this for m columns, row count doesn't matter.